# ServiceStack 3.9 build warning

Tags: .net, servicestack

I get this build warning when I try to build my project:

```
...\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.71\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll : warning CS1684: Reference to type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ApiMemberAttribute' claims it is defined in '...\packages\ServiceStack.Common.3.9.11\lib\net35\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll', but it could not be found
```

This is my packages.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <packages>
    <package id="ServiceStack" version="3.9.71" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="3.9.11" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="3.9.14" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="ServiceStack.Redis" version="3.9.11" targetFramework="net40" />
    <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.38" targetFramework="net40" />
 </packages>
```

This is the result of:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure all ServiceStack versions are the same. From the [instructions on the ServiceStack v3 home page](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3):

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack -Version 3.9.71 -DependencyVersion Highest
```